# Argument type mismatch in hive action via OOZIE

Tags: hive, oozie

I am running hive action in oozie, where hive.sql script has the below mentioned hive query.

Agenda:

1. Goal is to insert the outcome of this query into hive integrated hbase table, where main goal is to retrieve latest timestamp via transaction_dt column.
2. However when I run the same query via hive action in OOZIE, it fails with

error message:

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: Line 0:-1 Argument
>   type mismatch 'rows': The 1st argument of EQUAL  is expected to a
>   primitive type, but list is found

3. Seems like UDF defined variable is not expected here, however primitive type is expected.

   When I run this query manually on hive shell, it works perfectly.

```
    insert overwrite table hive_lookup_hbase

    Select lookup.card_id, lookup.UCL, lookup.postcode, lookup.transaction_dt,lookup.score
    from
    (
    SELECT ct.card_id, row_number() over ( partition by ct.card_id order by ct.transaction_dt desc ) rows,
    ct.postcode , ct.member_id, ct.transaction_dt, ms.score, c_u_look.UCL
    FROM hive_cardtrans_hbase ct 
         join cid_ucl_lookup c_u_look 
         join member_score ms on c_u_look.card_id=ct.card_id and ms.member_id=ct.member_id
    )lookup

    where rows=1;
```

As it works with hive shell, needs to know what changes I can make to make it work with oozie.

Comment: Wild guess: Try to rename `rows` alias with `row_num`

Comment: row_num is just alias right, I have tried renaming it  to just r, however no go

Comment: tried row_num as well, however no go.

Comment: Tested it and found issue vanished if I don't use join in oozie, however  it works normally in hive shell with joins, so don't know which changes needs to be done to make it work with oozie.

Comment: BTW in this join: join cid_ucl_lookup c_u_look ON condition is not on it's place. Check the EXPLAIN plan, it is CROSS join most probably

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure is this responsible for exception but obviously the join without ON condition is bad thing because it is CROSS JOIN. It seems the ON condition for the first join is not where it should be. It should be like this, isn't it?

```
FROM hive_cardtrans_hbase ct 
         join cid_ucl_lookup c_u_look on c_u_look.card_id=ct.card_id
         join member_score   ms       on ms.member_id=ct.member_id
```

not this:

```
FROM hive_cardtrans_hbase ct 
         join cid_ucl_lookup c_u_look 
         join member_score   ms on c_u_look.card_id=ct.card_id and ms.member_id=ct.member_id
```

Comment: No tried this change as well, however no go, my query works in hive shell, however fails in OOZIE.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got fixed by setting the set hive.auto.convert.join=false in hive script.
This basically disables the optimization done by OOZIE, i thought, this option was disabled by default.